# Fragment appearing on top of another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tabbed Android Application that uses Fragments on each page of the tab. I have a button inside of a fragment, and I use that button to bring another fragment on to the screen. The button works as you can see the second Fragment when it is pressed, the only problem is that the second Fragment appears over the first fragment, making the text in the second Fragment unreadable as the text from the first fragment is behind it. How do I get the first Fragment to go away when the second Fragment appears.

Here is the code for the button listener.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Fragment frag = new ContactsFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: post the code where you add the first fragment

Comment: Is your first fragment using R.id.fragment_container?  or it's something else?

Comment: @uDevel the first fragment uses R.id.fragment_container.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the second `Fragment` background of your root view with a desired color.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<TextView
    android:text="Hi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```